# Is there something similar to the Notepad++ session workflow?

Tags: editors, text, productivity

Is tmux+vim/nano the closest thing to the Notepad++ workflow (in recent versions of Notepad++ that automatically save session state)?
I really miss that, it was convenient to just dump text I copied out of the browser to Notepad++ and just come back to it some time later, but I'm not sure what the closest thing in Linux is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On command line, vim/tmux is probably the closest you'll come. For desktop apps, Sublime Text will restore anything opened with any changes you made (saved or no). There is a feature request [here](https://discuss.atom.io/t/add-remember-open-tabs/104/30) to add this to Atom, and the [save-session](https://github.com/mpeterson2/save-session) plugin is available until such a time as it's rolled into the core (which may be never, admittedly).

Edit: There is also a plugin for gedit available [here](https://github.com/sphax3d/gedit-sessionsaver)

Comment: Atom is too much overhead for such a simple task. ST is a possibility but it's non-free and that's a step-down from NPP. I think I'll wait for more answers but thanks.

Comment: Looks like there's a plugin available for gedit as well [here](https://github.com/sphax3d/gedit-sessionsaver). Do you have a preferred editor for this? There seems to be plugins for most popular editors that you can find by searching for <editor name> save session

Comment: Thanks I'll give that a try. I don't really have a particular editor, I'll adapt to whatever I'm given, gedit is fine. All it needs to do is to be able to maintain the session state once the program is closed, without prompting me for confirmation about saving each file individually. That's what NPP does and it is underappreciated how nice that is.